# Can UICollectionViewUpdateItem be used to update a single label?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to update a single label in a collection view cell.  I know how to update the entire collection view and how to update a single cell, but I want to update only a label because if the whole cell updates it will change other stuff which I don't want to change yet.  In the docs I found something called UICollectionViewUpdateItem but cannot figure out how to use it.  Is this capable of updating a single label or if not is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the index path of the cell you want to update, you can get the cell using `cellForItem(at: IndexPath)`. From there you can edit your cell's label.

However, I suggest you don't change your underlying data so that it's in a state that is unsuitable for presentation in the UI. The collection view can decide to create cells at times that are unpredictable to you.

`UICollectionViewUpdateItem` is used to indicate e.g. from where a cell moved, and where it moved to, or that a cell at a certain position was deleted, updated, etc. The docs state:

> You do not create instances of this class directly.

So it means you should only create it indirectly, for example through `reloadItems(at: [IndexPath])`. It will reload your entire cell and should not be used to update a single detail of it.

Comment: That's good info but how do I update the label without updating the entire cell?  For example if there's an animation happening in the cell, and I want to update the label, I don't want to cancel out the animation.

Comment: I would calculate its index path, get the cell, access its label (through a property if you have a custom cell class, or using `viewWithTag`) and assign to its `text`.

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to do lol that's what i don't understand how to do.  Okay before submitting this comment I think I figured out what you mean. That's the answer I was looking for.  I didn't realize you could access label.text from cellforitem() I thought it wouldn't update it unless you reload cell or table

Comment: It's not updating this way